# SceneKit - Draw 3D Parabola

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3d, scenekit

I'm given three points and need to draw a smooth 3D parabola. The trouble is that curved line is choppy and has some weird divots in it

[image: parabola]

Here is my code...

```
func drawJump(jump: Jump){
    let halfDistance = jump.distance.floatValue/2 as Float
    let tup = CalcParabolaValues(0.0, y1: 0.0, x2: halfDistance, y2: jump.height.floatValue, x3: jump.distance.floatValue, y3: 0)
    println("tuple \tup")

    var currentX = 0 as Float
    var increment = jump.distance.floatValue / Float(50)
    while currentX < jump.distance.floatValue - increment {

        let x1 = Float(currentX)
        let x2 = Float((currentX+increment))
        let y1 = calcParabolaYVal(tup.a, b: tup.b, c: tup.c, x: x1)
        let y2 = calcParabolaYVal(tup.a, b: tup.b, c: tup.c, x: x2)

        drawLine(x1, y1: y1, x2: x2, y2: y2)

        currentX += increment
    }
}

func CalcParabolaValues(x1: Float, y1: Float, x2: Float, y2: Float, x3: Float, y3: Float) -> (a: Float, b: Float, c: Float) {
    println(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    let a = y1/((x1-x2)*(x1-x3)) + y2/((x2-x1)*(x2-x3)) + y3/((x3-x1)*(x3-x2))
    let b = (-y1*(x2+x3)/((x1-x2)*(x1-x3))-y2*(x1+x3)/((x2-x1)*(x2-x3))-y3*(x1+x2)/((x3-x1)*(x3-x2)))
    let c = (y1*x2*x3/((x1-x2)*(x1-x3))+y2*x1*x3/((x2-x1)*(x2-x3))+y3*x1*x2/((x3-x1)*(x3-x2)))

    return (a, b, c)
}

func calcParabolaYVal(a:Float, b:Float, c:Float, x:Float)->Float{
    return a * x * x + b * x + c
}

func drawLine(x1: Float, y1: Float,x2: Float, y2: Float) {
    println("drawLine \(x1) \(y1) \(x2) \(y2)")
    let positions: [Float32] = [
        x1, y1, 0,
        x2, y2, 0
    ]
    let positionData = NSData(bytes: positions, length: sizeof(Float32)*positions.count)
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
    let indexData = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(Int32) * indices.count)

    let source = SCNGeometrySource(data: positionData, semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, vectorCount: indices.count, floatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float32), dataOffset: 0, dataStride: sizeof(Float32) * 3)
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Line, primitiveCount: indices.count, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(Int32))

    let line = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    self.rootNode.addChildNode( SCNNode(geometry: line))
}

func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    glLineWidth(20)
}
```

I also have to figure out how to animate the arc from left to right. Can someone help me out? Swift or Objective C is fine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will the points be arbitrary?

Comment: The points will be (0, 0), ( distance/2, maxHeight), (distance, 0)

Comment: 8 stars and just 1 up-vote... Guys remember, up votes are free.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`SCNShape`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShape_Class/index.html) to create your parabola. To start, you'll need to represent your parabola as a Bézier curve. You can use [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html) for that. For animation, I personally find [shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) are a nice fit for cases like this.

#### The Parabola

Watch out, though — you probably want a path that represents just the open stroke of the arc. If you do something like this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPointZero)
path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200))
```

You'll get a filled-in parabola, like this (seen in 2D in the debugger quick look, then extruded in 3D with `SCNShape`):

[image: filled parabola][image: filled parabola in 3D]

To create a closed shape that's just the arc, you'll need to trace back over the curve, a little bit away from the original:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPointZero)
path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 99, y: 0))
path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 198))
```

[image: open parabola][image: open parabola in 3D]

That's better.

#### ... in Three-Dee!

How to actually make it 3D? Just make an `SCNShape` with the extrusion depth you like:

```
let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 10)
```

And set it in your scene:

```
shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = SKColor.blueColor()
let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
shapeNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(50, 0, 0)
shapeNode.eulerAngles.y = Float(-M_PI_4)
root.addChildNode(shapeNode)
```

Here I'm using a `pivot` to make the shape rotate around the major axis of the parabola, instead of the `y = 0` axis of the planar Bézier curve. And making it blue. Also, `root` is just a shortcut I made for the view's scene's root node.

#### Animating

The shape of the parabola doesn't really need to change through your animation — you just need a visual effect that progressively reveals it along its x-axis. [Shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) are a great fit for that, because you can make the animated effect per-pixel instead of per-vertex and do all the expensive work on the GPU.

Here's a shader snippet that uses a `progress` parameter, varying from 0 to 1, to set opacity based on x-position:

```
// declare a variable we can set from SceneKit code
uniform float progress;
// tell SceneKit this shader uses transparency so we get correct draw order
#pragma transparent
// get the position in model space
vec4 mPos = u_inverseModelViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);
// a bit of math to ramp the alpha based on a progress-adjusted position
_surface.transparent.a = clamp(1.0 - ((mPos.x + 50.0) - progress * 200.0) / 50.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Set that as a shader modifier for the Surface entry point, and then you can animate the `progress` variable:

```
let modifier = "uniform float progress;\n #pragma transparent\n vec4 mPos = u_inverseModelViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);\n _surface.transparent.a = clamp(1.0 - ((mPos.x + 50.0) - progress * 200.0) / 50.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
shape.shaderModifiers = [ SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface: modifier ]
shape.setValue(0.0, forKey: "progress")

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(10)
shape.setValue(1.0, forKey: "progress")
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

[image: animating parabola]

#### Further Considerations

[Here's the whole thing](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e84cc9084ab8d631f79) in a form you can paste into a (iOS) playground. A few things left as exercises to the reader, plus other notes:

- Factor out the magic numbers and make a function or class so you can alter the size/shape of your parabola. (Remember that you can scale SceneKit nodes relative to other scene elements, so they don't have to use the same units.)
- Position the parabola relative to other scene elements. If you take away my line that sets the `pivot`, the `shapeNode.position` is the left end of the parabola. Change the parabola's length (or scale it), then rotate it around its y-axis, and you can make the other end line up with some other node. (For you to [fire ze missiles at?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCpjgl2baLs))
- I threw this together with Swift 2 beta, but I don't think there's any Swift-2-specific syntax in there — porting back to 1.2 if you need to deploy soon should be straightforward.
- If you also want to do this on OS X, it's a bit trickier — there, `SCNShape` uses `NSBezierPath`, which unlike `UIBezierPath` doesn't support quadratic curves. Probably an easy way out would be to fake it with an elliptical arc.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much.  I ended up solving my problem using SCNGeometryElement, but this works better and is so much cleaner.  I am forever grateful.

Comment: Does the animation in the playground still work for you on Xcode 7.2?  I can get any single value of "progress" to display properly, but wrapping it in an animation block stops that change from occurring.

// Animate the shader modifier variable
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(10)
shape.setValue(1.0, forKey: "progress")
SCNTransaction.commit()

Comment: I wish we could vote on "best posts", because this is definitely one of them.

Comment: Could you please explain me, why you slightly changed the coordinates of the path when traced back over the curve?

Comment: That gives the parabola some thickness (in 2D, before extrusion), which is needed because extrusion into 3D uses the filled-in 2D area of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your table has enough points, assuming the renderer is connecting them with straight line segments. On top of this, the thickness and dashing of the line make it difficult to see that. Try getting a smooth curve with a thin solid line first.

If you want to animate the progression of the curve, as if it were showing the flight of a projectile, it will probably be easiest to just write your function for the motion: y = k*x^2, and just render from x=0 to x=T for increasing values of T.